# jQuery hide/show issue with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a navbar on my website that is too wide for all buttons to display on mobiles devices. So I want to hide when the offset of the navigation buttons from the viewport is less than 150px (a drop down will take it's place). If there is more than 150px offset, then the navbar needs to be displayed.

I have made a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnwacrzq/2/) that shows what I want (resize the window). It correctly hides the navbar from view, but it won't make it appear again if there offset is greater than 150.

I know this happens because the element gets width "auto" and so the condition cannot be checked, but I don't know a workaround for this.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">Some</div>
        <div class="item">Example</div>
        <div class="item">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var offset = $('.container').offset();
    if (offset.left < 150) {
        $('.container').hide();
    } else {
        $('.container').show();
    }
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that once you hide something, it is no longer rendered and so it does not know the .offset() of the container.

Maybe try css "visibility" instead?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hnwacrzq/5/

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var offset = $('.container').offset();
    console.log(offset);
    if (offset.left < 150) {
        $('.container').css("visibility", "hidden");
    } else {
        $('.container').css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: Yup! Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: PS: You had `collapse` before, but changed it to `hidden`. What's the difference?

Comment: collapse was used for tables only. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp